# Send zipped files to Web API - Error: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream, dotnet-httpclient, sharpziplib

I need to read a bunch of files from disk, archive them on the fly and send to the Web API zipped from Memory stream. But every time I get error Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

My code works fine if I save zip file to local disk and then open FileStream and send it to the WebAPI, But I need to do it on the fly without saving. Here is my code:

```
using (MemoryStream mZip = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipOutputStream zipOStream = new ZipOutputStream(mZip))
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fi in allFiles)
        {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry((fi.Name));
            zipOStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fi.FullName);

            try
            {
                byte[] transferBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = fs.Read(transferBuffer, 0, transferBuffer.Length);
                    zipOStream.Write(transferBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                while (bytesRead > 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password) }))
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppConfig.ServerApiURL);                                
                var streamContent = new StreamContent(mZip);
                streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "Filename.zip",  Size = mZip.Length
                };

                content.Add(streamContent);
                var result = client.PostAsync("Log/PostLog", content).Result;
                MessageBox.Show(result.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error

> "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written"

is at `client.PostAsync("Log/PostLog", content).Result;`
If I repalce MemoryStream mZip with FileStream this code saves proper zip file so I suppose there is no problem with contenet length.

If I close ZipOutputStream zipOStream before sending then MemoryStream mZip is also closed and can not be sent.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Memory Stream object's i.e mZip.Postion to zero as below before adding to StreamContent

mZip.Position = 0 ;